# How to terminate a worker thread correctly in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

**Problem statement**

I have a worker thread that basically scans a folder, going into the files within it, and then sleeps for a while. The scanning operation might take 2-3 seconds but not much more. I'm looking for a way to stop this thread elegantly.

**Clarification**: I want to stop the thread while it's *sleeping*, and not while it's *scanning*. However, the problem is that I do not know what is the current state of the thread. If it's sleeping I want it to exit immediately. If it's scanning, I want it to exit the moment it tries to block.

**Attempts at a solution**

At first I was using Sleep and Interrupt. Then I found out that Interrupt doesn't really interrupt the Sleep - it only works when the threads TRIES to go into sleeping.

So I switched to Monitor Wait&Pulse. Then I found out that the Pulse only works when I'm actually in the Wait. So now I have a thread which looks like that:

```
while (m_shouldRun)
{
    try
    {
        DoSomethingThatTakesSeveralSeconds();
        lock (this)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(this, 5000);
        }
    }
    catch (ThreadInterruptedException)
    {
        m_shouldRun = false;
    }
}
```

And now I need to craft my Stop function. So I started with:

```
public void Stop()
{
    m_shouldRun = false;
    lock (this)
    {
        Monitor.Pulse(this);
    }
    thread.Join();
}
```

But this doesn't work because I may be pulsing while the thread works (while it's not waiting). So I added Interrupt:

```
public void Stop()
{
    m_shouldRun = false;
    thread.Interrupt();
    lock (this)
    {
        Monitor.Pulse(this);
    }
    thread.Join();
}
```

Another option is to use:

```
public void Stop()
{
    m_shouldRun = false;
    while (!thread.Join(1000))
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            Monitor.Pulse(this);
        }
    }
}
```

**The question**

What is the preferred method? Is there a third method which is preferable?

Comment: "*At first I was using Sleep and Interrupt. Then I found out that Interrupt doesn't really interrupt the Sleep - it only works when the threads TRIES to go into sleeping.*" That's strange. Is this a known bug? If it isn't, can you try to reproduce it with a toy example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another alternative is to use events:

```
private ManualResetEvent _event = new ManualResetEvent(false);


public void Run() 
{
 while (true)
 {
    DoSomethingThatTakesSeveralSeconds();
    if (_event.WaitOne(timeout))
      break;
 }
}

public void Stop() 
{
   _event.Set();
   thread.Join();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this will work as well. The question is what would be the best way of doing it. Your option does look better than the recurring Pulse or the Interrupt+Pulse.

Comment: Well, personally I would not use Pulse/Interrupts. Pulse might be problematic due to possible APCs (I believe it might go unnoticed by the thread). Interrupts don't have a good reputation: http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2007/08/23/ThreadInterruptsAreAlmostAsEvilAsThreadAborts.aspx

Comment: If you have only one thread doing the job, go with an event. Otherwise  with a volatile flag and a timeout to wake-up and check whether the flag is set or not (avoids creating a lot of events which are kernel objects).

Answer (score 10):

The way to stop a thread elegantly is to leave it finish by itself. So inside the worker method you could have a boolean variable which will check whether we want to interrupt. By default it will be set to `false` and when you set it to `true` from the main thread it will simply stop the scanning operation by breaking from the processing loop.

Comment: +1 for allowing thread to finish by itself. Any other approach is messy. Don't forget to mark the boolean flag with the volatile keyword.

Comment: Thanks. You'll notice that I do have such a flag. I do not interrupt the thread while it's actually working, but I do want to interrupt it while it's sleeping. If it's going to sleep 10 minutes, I don't want it to continue sleeping.

Comment: A thread that's sleeping for 10 seconds is not useful to anyone. Use the `ThreadPool` to draw threads whenever you need to perform some tasks but don't leave them sleeping. Make them do useful stuff.

Comment: @Darin: This thread should periodically scan a folder. It's not event-based. How would you suggest I take an instance from the ThreadPool and run the scan every 10 minutes? Also, it's not like I have a resources problem here, because I don't have many threads such as this one in my application. I guess I could be using timers, but I'm not sure I like that idea.

Comment: *How would you suggest I take an instance from the ThreadPool and run the scan every 10 minutes*: By using the [ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.registerwaitforsingleobject.aspx) method and setting the `executeOnlyOnce` parameter to false. When you decode to stop simply unregister the wait handle with [RegisteredWaitHandle.Unregister](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.registeredwaithandle.unregister.aspx).

Comment: Interesting. Let's see if I got it right. From my main thread I call RegisterWaitForSingleObject, with, say, 10min timeout, and with the "DoSomething" function as the callBack. I never signal the waitObject, so the trigger will only occur after 10 minutes. Once the callback is done - the wait will start again. Isn't that just delegating the "thread" to .NET? I mean - the waiting thread will exist anyhow, won't it?

Comment: @Eldad Mor, alternative to sleeping 10 minutes is splitting that time to sleep for instance 10 consequent times by 1 minute and checking whether exit flag was set.

Comment: @Regent, wouldn't that be a busy wait (even though it will be sleeping most of the time)? If I want the thread to exit "immediately" I'll need to divide the interval into 10ms sections under that method.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to keep it simple:

```
while (m_shouldRun)
{
    DoSomethingThatTakesSeveralSeconds();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)  // example: 5 seconds sleep
    {
        if (!m_shouldRun)
            break;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

public void Stop()
{
    m_shouldRun = false;
    // maybe thread.Join();
}
```

This has the following advantages:

- It smells like busy waiting, but it's not. $NUMBER_OF_SECONDS checks are done during the waiting phase, which is not comparable to the thousands of checks done in real busy waiting.
- It's simple, which greatly reduces the risk of error in multi-threaded code. All your `Stop` method needs to do is to set `m_shouldRun` to false and (maybe) call `Thread.Join` (if it is necessary for the thread to finish before `Stop` is left). No synchronization primitives are needed (except for marking `m_shouldRun` as volatile).

Comment: The DoSomething function will not be forcefully interrupted. Thread.Interrupt only "happens" when the thread tries to block. See the MS documentation (here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt.aspx) - "If this thread is not currently blocked in a wait, sleep, or join state, it will be interrupted when it next begins to block."

Comment: @Eldad: Good point, I confused it with Thread.Abort. Changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with separately scheduling the task:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ProjectEuler
{
    class Program
    {
        //const double cycleIntervalMilliseconds = 10 * 60 * 1000;
        const double cycleIntervalMilliseconds = 5 * 1000;
        static readonly System.Timers.Timer scanTimer =
            new System.Timers.Timer(cycleIntervalMilliseconds);
        static bool scanningEnabled = true;
        static readonly ManualResetEvent scanFinished =
            new ManualResetEvent(true);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            scanTimer.Elapsed +=
                new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(scanTimer_Elapsed);
            scanTimer.Enabled = true;

            Console.ReadLine();
            scanningEnabled = false;
            scanFinished.WaitOne();
        }

        static void  scanTimer_Elapsed(object sender,
            System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            scanFinished.Reset();
            scanTimer.Enabled = false;

            if (scanningEnabled)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Processing");
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
                }
                finally
                {
                    scanTimer.Enabled = scanningEnabled;
                    scanFinished.Set();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```