# How to properly shutdown a logging thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, application-shutdown

I have a logging class that contains a thread-safe queue, a `Thread` to service that queue, some supporting signals, and a `bool`:

```
private ConcurrentQueue<LogEntry> _logQ;
private Thread _thread;
private volatile bool _running;
private AutoResetEvent _logEntryWaitingSignal;
private ManualResetEvent _shutdownSignal;
```

Constructor body:

```
{
    _logEntryWaitingSignal = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    _shutdownSignal = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    _logQ = new ConcurrentQueue<XrayLogEntry>();
    _thread = new Thread(LoggingThread);
    _thread.IsBackground = false;
    _thread.Start();
}
```

My thread body:

```
private void LoggingThread()
{
    _running = true;
    LogStore theLog = ...

    // don't exit until all queued entries are written
    while (_running || !_logQ.IsEmpty)
    {
        LogEntry entry;
        int entryCount = 0;
        while (_logQ.TryDequeue(out entry))
        {
            theLog.WriteEntry(entry);
        }
        _logEntryWaitingSignal.WaitOne();
    }
    _shutdownSignal.Set();
}
```

I have this snippet of shutdown code that sets the `_running` Boolean to `false` (the queue can no longer be added to once `_running` is `false`), then signals the thread to wake up, then waits for its signal that it has processed all its waiting entries and exited:

```
_running = false;
try
{
    _logEntryWaitingSignal.Set(); // Wakes the thread
    // Wait for thread to complete
    if(!_shutdownSignal.WaitOne(THREAD_SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS))
        throw new Exception("Timed out waiting for thread to exit.");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ...
}
```

My question is: Can I ensure this code is called so that it will execute under any possible (orderly) process termination?

I have experimented with executing it from `Dispose`, and implementing the finalizer to call `Dispose`. It works fine as long as `Dispose` gets called, e.g., from the `FormClosed` event of my application dialog. However, I don't believe the finalizer is guaranteed to work the way I want, as it seems that even if the thread that owns the logger object exits, the thread will remain active at the `_logEntryWaitingSignal.WaitOne()` call, and the process never exits.

Of course, if I make it a background thread, the process will exit, but if I do that, how can I ensure that the thread won't be shut down somewhere in the middle of writing an entry?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698731/how-to-terminate-a-worker-thread-correctly-in-c-sharp

Comment: Why are you writing your own logger in the first place?  There are a ton of already implemented solutions.  Just use one of them, and if you *really* want to make your own, see how *they* solved this problem.

Comment: Why not use _thread.Join() instead of using the shutdownSignal?

Comment: I would make it a background thread anyway, just to avoid hanging on exit in corner cases. Apart from that, I don't see any race conditions in your code. You can set `_running`, etc. on the [`Application.ApplicationExit` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit(v=vs.110).aspx?ppud=4). Finally, it seems as though your logging store is not fault-tolerant -- what if there's an OS crash or power failure in the middle of a log entry being written? No matter what you do, you need to handle half-written log entries in the worst case.

Comment: I've framed the question as a logger to simplify my actual use case, which is part of a data collection system. The backing store is an SQLite database, so the consistency of a partially-completed transaction is handled by that. The main purpose of this thread is to isolate data collection threads from the variance in time that it may take to write data to disk. It is able to batch multiple entries into a single transaction, if they are available, yet completes the transaction immediately if none are waiting. My concern is less about a partial entry write, and more about entries left waiting.